# AlertDialog setmessage not working inside Asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-alertdialog, async-onprogressupdate

Below is my code my trying to display my progress in Asyntask via onProgressUpdate method but it aint showing in the alert diaalog. Only the initial message is shown.

```
 class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        private AlertDialog.Builder alert;
        private int progress = 0;
        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Bar Dialog
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            alert.setTitle("Downloading..");
            alert.setMessage("1");
            alert.setCancelable(false);
            alert.show();
        }

        /**
         * Downloading file in background thread
         */
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
            int count;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
                URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                conection.connect();

                // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100%
                // progress bar
                int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

                // download the file
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),
                        8192);

                // Output stream
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    // publishing the progress....
                    // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                    publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));

                    // writing data to file
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                // flushing output
                output.flush();

                // closing streams
                output.close();
                input.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * Updating progress bar
         */
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
            Log.d("Myapp","progress :"+progress[0]);
            alert.setMessage(""+progress[0]);
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         **/
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
}
}
```

As i have also written a log to show progress update in onProgressUpdate, the log is printed but the alert.setMessage in onProgressUpdate seems not set the message to my alert dialog.

Comment: I think it will better if you use ProgressDialog instead of AlertDialog.

Comment: you use setmessage not on alertdialog but builder. and how about replace middle argument type String with Integer?

Comment: @iroiroys yeah i was doin that wrong as i thought it would work that way, and yeah i changed middle argument type to integer Thanks..!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per your code, `alert` is an `AlertDialog.Builder` and not an `AlertDialog` itself. This raised a concern to me because the reason it might not be changing is because you already showed the builder, but not give to an `AlertDialog`. So I tried out a simple code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AlertDialog.Builder alert;
    private AlertDialog ad;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle("Downloading..");
        alert.setMessage("1");
        alert.setCancelable(false);
        ad = alert.show();


        Log.d("SAMPLE", "SET MESSAGE 2");
        alert.setMessage("2");

        Log.d("SAMPLE", "SET MESSAGE 3");
        ad.setMessage("3");
    }

}
```

At first, I just used the `alert.setMessage` (this is the `AlertDialog.Builder`), and the message did not change at all. But after putting it in an `AlertDialog` and then setting the message of the `AlertDialog` instance, the message changed. Care to try this approach out. Pass the `AlertDialog.Builder` to an `AlertDialog` first then, `setMessage` using the `AlertDialog` instance.

Docs for [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html) and [AlertDialog.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html).

Comment: You can simply use: ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

Comment: @Asama Yup. But I did it this way for clarity.

Comment: You can use that like this: AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create(); and than add text and title to ad and show that. So no need to add title and text first to the builder and than show that builder properties into the dialog. This way is more simple and clear as it use just the AlertDialog and doesn't create a separate builder ;).

Comment: theOldTown No problem. Do note of @Asama 's comment. It'd help to reduce LOC. :)

Comment: i kept the whole code as it is and changed the last line in onPre  ad = alert.show(); and then changed ad.setmessage Thanks..

Comment: It is important to note that `ad.setMessage()` **won't work unless** at least you called his `AlertDialog.Builder` `alert.setMessage()` first with `""` input (`null` input won't work also). It is a known issue, see issue at [https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36913966](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36913966)

Answer (score 0):

In your code you forget to build alert dialog. See this

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
    alertDialog.show();
```

you have to create a alert dialog from `private AlertDialog.Builder alert;`

Comment: It should be alert.create() as you are defining builder as alert and not alertdialogbuilder :)

Comment: @Asama the above code is an example code and the lower one the declaration from the question both of them are different code snippets

Comment: @Asama now I edit the answer according to the question's code

Comment: If you'd have used alertdialogbuilder.create() than it may have created confusion to those who are new to Android and Java. So if you say that he has to create dialog from the "alert" builder than it's better to use that to demonstrate the right implementation of the code you have provided ;). Hope you get it